# Angular 14: Why subtract 1 day when converting data toISOString()?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a calendar in a parent component, and I pass the selected date as a parameter via selector to a child component:

```
<p-card styleClass="card">
      <h4 class="mt-0">MarketDash</h4>
      <app-short-mkt-dash [dataDay] = "dataDay"></app-short-mkt-dash>
</p-card>
```

In the child component I receive the selected date as input and through the ngOnChange method, I convert the date to IsoString ("yyyy/mm/dd") and call a service responsible for going to the server by sending this date in the URL:

```
 @Input() dataDay: Date;

 ngOnChanges() {
    console.log("1 - Dataday",this.dataDay);
    this.getShortMktByDate();
  }

 private getShortMktByDate() {    
    let newDay = this.dataDay
      .toISOString()
      .slice(0,10); //Get date format like: "yyyy/MM/dd"

      console.log("1 - newDay",newDay);
      console.log("2 - Dataday",this.dataDay);

      this.mktDashService
        .getShortMktByDate(newDay)
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.endSubscribe$))
        .subscribe((mkt: ShortMarketModel[]) => {
          this.shortMktList = mkt;
    })
  }
```

[image: The result I get is that the newDataDay is subtracted one day for no reason:]

Does anyone have any idea what could be happening?

Comment: `what could be happening?` - at 0:43 GMT+1, the date at UTC is 23:43 on the day before - `toISOString` outputs UTC date

Comment: try this - `newDay = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("fr-CA", {
        year: "numeric",
        month: "2-digit",
        day: "2-digit",
    }).format(this.dataDay);`

Comment: use `toLocaleDateString` instead of `toISOString`. It's happen because `toISOString` is wasn't calculating browser timezone.

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX, your solution solve the subtraction problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Without converting date to ISO format, it will display your local time (with time zone included).

ISO format is independent of the time zone.

You should consider doing everything in ISO format, especially if you need to send data to the server for processing.

Comment: I don't think they WANT to subtract a day - I think they are asking why the day is wrong (which it will be for 1 hour every day in GMT+1

Comment: You are right! I assumed they want to substract a day based on the question title. I updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yes as @Jaromanda X said my question is why this conversion is subtracting one day... However, I have already managed to solve this problem with colleague Jaromanda X solution, using: newDay = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("fr-CA", { year: "numeric",  month: "2-digit", day: "2-digit"}).format(this.dataDay);